# Async NUnit Test Method passing post the await call

Tags: c#, async-await, nunit, extentreports

I am writing NUnit Test for async methods and am using extent reporting to report the results. The ExtentTest linked to my test get completed as soon as the await step i the test method has completed execution and am no longer able to access the ExtentTest for any logging purpose. Is there any issue with my code or is this expected ?

Here is my Test method:

```
[Test, RequiresThread]

public async Task GetList()
{
    try
    {
        ReportHelper.ExtentTestInfo("system.readResources() method is called");
        Resources resources = await system.readResources();
        ReportHelper.ExtentTestInfo("system.readResources() method finished and responded");

        //Test Assertions
    }
}
```

Here is my ReportHelper class:

```
public class ReportHelper
 {

      private static ExtentReports TestReportHTML = new ExtentReports();

      var htmlReporter = new ExtentV3HtmlReporter("Test_Run_Report_" + @".html");

      TestReportHTML.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);

      [ThreadStatic] private static ExtentTest _extentTest;

      _extentTest = TestReportHTML.CreateTest(testName); //testName is passed during [SetUp]

    public static void ExtentTestInfo(string testInfo)
     {
        _extentTest.Info(testInfo);
     }
 }
```

Once the await call has been executed the _extentTest status is passed and on the next line I am getting NullReferenceException for the _extentTest

Comment: Have you tried removing the `[ThreadStatic]` attribute? That stops the variable being shared between threads but `await` may cause the code to execute on a different thread, which is causing your `_extentTest` to be null after the `await`.

Comment: Where are you calling `GetList`?

Comment: @JohanP GetList is one of my test methods. Corrected the test attributes in question

Comment: @SimplyGed: Thank you, removing the [ThreadStatic] attribute resolves the issue for me as of now. But if I want to run my test in parallel (say in future) and every test has to run on its own thread then this will not work as all test will have only one _extentTest to work with. Any suggestions around this ?

Comment: @test_user Just make ReportHelper non static and create a new instance at the start of each test. That would allow multiple tests to run concrrently.

Comment: Great news :-) I'm not familiar with `ExtentTest` but they do have some [thread safe examples](http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/net/#extent-nunit-parallel) on their document site. Have you tried them?

Comment: @Scott - That's what I thought originally but will the `new ExtentV3HtmlReporter("Test_Run_Report_" + @".html");` cause a new file to be created or append to an existing one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `[ThreadStatic]` attribute. That stops the variable being shared between threads but `await` may cause the code to execute the remaining code on a different thread, which is causing your _extentTest to be null after the await.